# Accessing "Salesforce Files Settings" in Apex

Tags: files

Is it possible to see in Apex if an org has the following setting enabled?

> Files uploaded to the Attachments related list on records are uploaded
>   as Salesforce Files, not as attachments

It doesn't have to be an explicit boolean that I can call; even if running a query could give me the answer that'd work just as well.

If not is it possible via the API at least?

Comment: Seems like it would have been made available in the [`ConnectApi.Features`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_features.htm) class alongside the `HasFilesSync` property. It's also not in the profiles, permission sets or UserInfo, or Organization output nor in the Chatter API as far as I can tell...